# Jenkins 431 Fields to large when remove credentials

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to remove credentials from Jenkins, but I got '431 Fields to large' because is id 'XML',

[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKPUK.png)
[Can't remove credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvisP.png)

thank you in advance

regards

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access the /var/lib/jenkins directory and here there are credentials.xml, I deleted them manually.